# Dynamically convert List<Object> to List<Customer>

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, system.reflection

I have a list, the type of the object will be found only at the runtime through reflection. But when I try to assign the list to the actual entity, it is throwing error as "object cannot be converted". Below is the code,

```
var obj = new List<Object>();
obj.Add(cust1);
obj.Add(Cust2);
Type newType = t.GetProperty("Customer").PropertyType// I will get type from property
var data= Convert.ChangeType(obj,newType); //This line throws error`
```

Comment: `Type t = t.GetProperty("Customer").PropertyType// I will get type from property` -- you're defining a variable and using the variable at the same time. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why *exactly* do you need a `List<Customer>`? From the description, it sounds like you want to convert a `List<Object>` to a `List<T>` where `T` is determined at run time, but then `data` will have to have type `object` because it can hold any `List<T>`. This makes your code even more weakly typed.

Comment: Something like this?: `List<Customer> Customers = obj.Select(O => (Customer)O.GetType().GetProperty("Customer").GetValue(O, null)).ToList();`

Comment: I just shown that code as example. I will get the list of Object from different system and the type name as string. I will need to convert them dynamically.

Comment: @sabaedge - What are the types of `cust1` and `cust2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `obj` object ist not a `Customer`, it's a `List` of `Customer`. 
So you should get the type of it this way:

```
var listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(t);
```

But you couldn't convert your object to to this `listType`, you will get an `Exception`, that `List` doesn't implement `IConvertible` interface.

Solution is: just to create new list and copy all data to it:

```
object data = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
foreach (var o in obj)
{
     listType.GetMethod("Add").Invoke(data, new []{o} );
}
```